# error using kohana 3.3.3.1 mysqli

Tags: mysqli, kohana-3.3

I have put [this](https://github.com/tomlankhorst/kohana-3.3-mysqli) driver to `MODPATH/database` and changed type to 'MySQLi' in APPPATH/config/database.php and got an error `Class 'Database_MySQLi_Result' not found`. What am I doing wrong?

```
PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6
MySQL 5.5.37
```

Comment: Does the file exist under `MODPATH/database/classes/MySQLi/Result.php`?

Comment: yes, it does. full way is `MODPATH/database/classes/Database/MySQLi/Result.php`

Comment: Ah yes, that is the correct path (not the one I asked about) - sorry, I have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I set access rights to the folder to 777.

Comment: That is probably a bit too much, you can and should be more restrictive with those rights. Did you check which user/group the files belong to?